# Pass Multiple Select Values Through PHP

Tags: php, select

I want to pass multiple select values through PHP using multiple select box. I'm trying this code;

```
<select name="fid[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

I want to collect `fid` values (which receives in an array) as comma separated values in a PHP function, like `1,2,3` How to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: hidden input should do it

Comment: Please understand, I've searched and googled and haven't find an answer about my issue.

Comment: How to use javascript? Thanks.

Comment: look into jquery post. Then you can use php serialize and unserialize to unwrap/wrap arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using `$_POST['fid']` to collect `fid` values. Using `implode()` in the way posted above should work. e.g.

```
$fids = implode(",",$_POST['fid']);
```

and then use `$fids` var to insert or update your sql db.

Comment: ah! thanks. I was using another variable actually, my bad!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, it's most likely not the best idea, but, assuming your form is POST method:

```
$list = implode(',', $_POST['fid']);
```

Comment: Not worked. It sends `0` when I select multiple values

Comment: Huh.?.?. `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's implode function like this:

```
$array = $_POST['fid'];
$csv_string = implode(",", $array);
```

$csv_string will contain then the values you need, comma separated.

Comment: Not worked. It sends `0` when I select multiple values